# PHP - filesize() returns an empty string

Tags: php, file, amazon-s3, filesize

I have a strange problem. I have an image which i need to upload to a file server. I 'm using php to do this. The image permissions are the following

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache  148041 Dec 22 08:25 Not.jpg
```

I checked that the file exists. I have downloaded the file and found it to be ok. it's original size is 60 KB. Permissions are also fine.

When I do the following

```
$filepath = "../uploads/".$file_name;
$image = fopen($filepath, "rb");
echo file_exists($filepath).' ';
echo filesize($filepath). 'bytes ';
echo exif_read_data($filepath). ' ';
```

The output is 
    `1 bytes  200`

```
1 - File Exists
bytes - This is where the error occurs. filesize() is returning an empty string here
200 - server response
```

What is the correct way to load this file ?

Comment: try using an absolute path.

Comment: @roullie Thanks for the quick reply. I tried that. But it's still the same.

Comment: can you try it with `getimagesize` just check if this function also returning same value

Comment: also enable error reporting and check `filesize` function as Upon failure, an E_WARNING will be emitted.

Comment: @ChetanAmeta getimagesize returned false

Comment: is there any warning after turning on error_reporting in filesize function

Comment: @ChetanAmeta No Warning after turning on error_reporting.

Answer (score -2):

As reference to [fopen manual of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) the modes should be either read or write. You are using undefined mode rb. try using this

```
$image = fopen($filepath, "r");
```

Comment: You didn't read the **Note** section of the documentation. The third paragraph explains the `b` flag that goes after the mode: **To use these flags, specify either 'b' or 't' as the last character of the mode parameter.**